# How to concatenate same row names in same column on Python DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I have a simple dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'class':['a','b','c','d','e'],
                  'name':['Adi','leon','adi','leo','andy'],
                  'age':['9','8','9','9','8'],
                   'score':['40','90','35','95','85']})
```

then the result is like this

```
 class  name   age  score
    a   Adi     9   40
    b   leon    8   90
    a   adi     9   35
    d   leo     9   95
    e   andy    8   85
```

how can I combine the row named 'Adi' with 'adi' in the same column while he is only one person and the score 'Adi' is 75, not 40 and 35

Comment: You can convert them all to upper or lower and then group them summing the score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) after first making the `name` column lowercase:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'class': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'name': ['Adi', 'leon', 'adi', 'leo', 'andy'],
    'age': ['9', '8', '9', '9', '8'],
    'score': ['40', '90', '35', '95', '85']
})
df['name'] = df['name'].str.lower()
df['score'] = df['score'].astype(int)
aggregate_funcs = {
    'class': lambda s: ', '.join(set(s)),
    'age': lambda s: ', '.join(set(s)),
    'score': sum
}
df = df.groupby(df['name']).aggregate(aggregate_funcs)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     class age  score
name                 
adi   c, a   9     75
andy     e   8     85
leo      d   9     95
leon     b   8     90
```

Comment: Regarding [your earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70788682/#comment125148633_70788682) (question got deleted, can't reply there): That's not O(1) space but O(n) space. For example for `nums = list(range(1, 10**6))`, `tracemalloc` reports you use 28 MB. As expected for a million `int` objects each taking 28 bytes.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant `O(1)` in terms of extra additional space, since `nums` has to be passed as an argument.

Comment: Not sure how you mean that. It isn't O(1) in terms of "extra additional" space. Unless you're defining that in a way I don't see? :-) You are creating 28 MB of additional data there. I have two ideas for similar solutions that really are O(1) extra space, one of them able to restore the data in the end (which I think is the least one should do in the real world... if you tried yours at work, I kinda doubt you'd get an LGTM :-)

Comment: Everything that you said makes sense, it would be O(N) in terms of space. I have however seen a few questions relating to API design for image processing in the interview question back, in terms of the manipulation of a 2D matrix of 1, 0's representing black and white pixels, like dilating, etc. In these questions, the author mentions if the candidate talks about the possibility of creating two separate functions i.e., one that is destructive on the input image (and the reasons for wanting one), and another one that makes and returns a modified copy, it is a positive signal.

Comment: I agree with that, although I'd say that's rather different, as the output in those cases is the modified matrix, right? I.e., modifying it can be the *desired* effect. In our case, on the other hand, the output is a single int, and your code modifies the input list not as the *desired* effect but as a *side* effect. *That's* what I think makes it not so good.

Comment: Meh... the first of my two ideas doesn't work. I thought I could maybe mark with just `True` instead. I.e., remember the occurrence of a number `num` by setting `nums[num - 1] = True` in a forwards-loop not overwriting later values and then a backwards-loop. But doesn't work. The second idea is to use `ctypes` to mess with the bytes of the `list` object similar to how I [just did for something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70882092/12671057). I think it would work, but it'd be messy and I'm not motivated enough. Btw let me know if you want us to delete our comments here.

Answer (score 1):

`drop_duplicates()` is the best way if you are using pandas

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.lower()
df['score'] = df['score'].astype(int)
df['score'] = df['score'].groupby(df['name']).transform(sum)
df.drop_duplicates(subset='name',keep='first',inplace=True)
```

output:

```
  class  name age  score
0     a   adi   9     75
1     b  leon   8     90
3     d   leo   9     95
4     e  andy   8     85
```

you will have this output if you set `keep='last'`:

```
  class  name age  score
1     b  leon   8     90
2     c   adi   9     75
3     d   leo   9     95
4     e  andy   8     85
```