# Can we make 1 == 2 true?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

Python `int`s are **objects** that encapsulate the actual number value. Can we mess with that value, for example setting the value of the object `1` to 2? So that `1 == 2` becomes `True`?

Comment: Reminds me of a story about a version of Fortran where. if you passed a literal `1` to a procedure, it could set the constant `1` equal to `-1` through that reference, and thanks to the compiler merging all references to the same literal, it would then make every loop in the program run backwards.

Comment: @Davislor Passing a literal 1 sounds like a normal thing to do, and modifying an argument does as well. So, was that not even a conscious hack like mine, but could actually happen unintentionally by accident? Scary...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clarification for "it should be possible to change the value of 1" from the CPython documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188158/clarification-for-it-should-be-possible-to-change-the-value-of-1-from-the-cpyt) or [Can 1 + 1 be equal to 3 in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53950215/1048572)

Comment: I tried to play a bit with https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit but didn't manage to redefine int#__eq__

Comment: Python's reference implementation (CPython) exposes an API for library developers and during my work on some C++ lib I was surprised how much stuff you can fiddle with from the inside. It basically exposes all type information about implementation and nothing stops you from interfering even with crucial elements like reference counts and memory addresses of specific (sub)objects. It feels just as if you were editing interpreter's code.

Comment: There is a similar question with different languages in the codegolf.SE: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5 You will find some python answers there as well.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Where integers are defined, in `that_would_be_nice/int.py`.

Comment: Ace left-handed programmer, James Marshall Hendrix, evolved a coding style that was immune to this defect: "Now if six turned out to be nine, I don't mind, I don't mind". [Link.](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/jimihendrix/if6was9.html)

Comment: In Javascript, one can make Math.PI = 2 (but later when you call Math.PI it loads again the default 3.14 ). The code is written as 
`console.log(Math.PI = 2); // 2` then  
`console.log(Math.PI); // 3.141592653589793`
 and can be understood as Math.PI extracting the value of property PI of the built-in object Math and assigning it with value of 2 (for a single instance only) then again extracting the original value of PI when executing the second line of code.

Comment: @Eric Duminil Yes, already read and upvoted it yesterday. If I ever want to do something like this again, I'll probably use the method shown there, as in general it's more convenient (although I still prefer `memmove` for my case here).

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Yes, we can. But **don't do this at home**. Seriously, the `1` object is used in many places and I have no clue what this might break and what that might do to your computer. I reject all responsibility. But I found it interesting to learn about these things.

The [`id` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) gives us the memory address and the [`ctypes` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) lets us mess with memory:

```
import ctypes

ctypes.memmove(id(1) + 24, id(2) + 24, 4)

print(1 == 2)

x = 40
print(x + 1)
```

Output:

```
True
42
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYoxDoAgEAT7e8WVEI0RpLDhNUoixcEFicHXnyRqNTOb5bseOS0rF5FInEvFrd4cToCXEwWifAUVd2U0DmjdiN3t704DcImpKoPeo@3Z0KObv7X1n9EiDw). I tried it there because such sites have got to be protected from our hacking anyway.

---

More explanation / analysis:

The `memmove` copied the value from the `2` object into the `1` object. Their size is 28 bytes each, but I skipped the first 24 bytes, because that's the object's reference count, type address, and value size, as we can view/verify as well:

```
import ctypes, struct, sys

x = 1
data = ctypes.string_at(id(x), 28)
ref_count, type_address, number_of_digits, lowest_digit = \
    struct.unpack('qqqi', data)

print('reference count: ', ref_count, sys.getrefcount(x))
print('type address:    ', type_address, id(type(x)))
print('number of digits:', number_of_digits, -(-x.bit_length() // 30))
print('lowest digit:    ', lowest_digit, x % 2**30)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBbsMgEETvfMVeKuPIcdrkElnKn1RCBLCDmgCGtWp/vbuEpo2q@oIZ7cybJSx48e5wDHFd7S34iKBwCSY1kDBOCulcEmMznOCNaYmSfspESwPWDUIit5rPdQP7Y82i6YXykyNjnhJS62gSxbnpdjZR@F5oO1gk5eo/TcJypdR3BvQVaju5INUHr8ZxtFUDGVwzFgiIvCKGicYpA3dSBzTxxKXC7WCQlLtA1eqHM1eC70pdxlV/a9IqWcimH1epDr6HUr2r/ltny7dze7YorsYNeOE17HZweP2NKfuWjAf8@Q0amOEF9psNmdb1Cw)):

```
reference count:  135 138
type address:     140259718753696 140259718753696
number of digits: 1 1
lowest digit:     1 1
```

The reference count gets increased by the `getrefcount` call, but I don't know why by 3. Anyway, ~134 things other than us reference the `1` object, and we're potentially messing all of them up, so... really don't try this at home.

The "digits" refer to how CPython stores `int`s as [digits in base 2<sup>30</sup>](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/247480a21cb165efdacc346a2d589dfc27e18283/Include/cpython/longintrepr.h#L11-L39). For example, `x = 2 ** 3000` has 101 such digits. Output for `x = 123 ** 456` for a better test:

```
reference count:  1 2
type address:     140078560107936 140078560107936
number of digits: 106 106
lowest digit:     970169057 970169057
```

Comment: Quick question, what is the meaning of the "21 .__sizeof__() - 24" argument? (I see it is changed to 4 instead now, it is the size?)

Comment: @RichardKYu I had originally used `1 + 1 == 42` as the target example, so had changed the value of `1` to 21 for that. Then when I switched to `1 == 2` as target example, I forgot to change `21` to `2` there in the code.

Comment: @ilkkachu I guess so. Better at home than at work, but still better to just try it on those online services with professionally sandboxed environments.

Comment: Obviously this works *only* in CPython. I'm pretty sure the Python language doesn't give any semantics to the value returned by `id` and this answer shows why using the memory address is probably not the best option... sure itis the simplest & fastest probably

Comment: For me this crashed the interpreter. Trying it with some more rarely used vales (17 and 18) did work!

Comment: @GACy20 Well, the question *is* tagged as being specific to CPython :-). I don't think it's obvious, though. That would require knowing it for every other implementation. How many people do? I certainly don't, I can't even *name* all of them. In any case, it doesn't really matter... like I said, this was just out of curiosity / for fun. I don't intend to actually *use* this for anything. I'm interested in how CPython works, so this was educational for me.

Comment: @Todd Sewell You daredevils... I wouldn't even try *that* on my PC. I considered trying it with a larger int after creating it myself and verifying that I have the only reference, but really I'm satisfied with doing it online.

Comment: This does not seem to work on Windows. :(

Comment: @Mezgrman: Did you try it in the python console? It segfaulted on mine. But it worked fine when running `python dont_do_this_at_home.py`.

Comment: @Eric Duminil: Yeah, both actually. It doesn't segfault, it just prints False and 41, respectively. (Python 3.7.4)

Comment: `print(list(range(10)))` #=> `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`. LOL. And by the way, there's a related Reddit thread with very similar code : https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2441cv/can_you_change_the_value_of_1/

Comment: @KellyBundy There's really not that much risk, the worst that can happen is some kind of segfault, which is not that rare when developing C/C++ software anyway. Processes are isolated by the OS, it will never end up taking down the entire PC.

Comment: @Eric Duminil Oh wow .. `range` did cross my mind but I didn't test it because I thought it's surely optimized for "normal" ranges to internally work with C integers and only produce Python ints when it has to produce them. Now I'm even more worried than before. And I shall look into what `range` really does.

Comment: @Todd Sewell I'm not worried about directly harming other processes, but about files. Either directly my own files, or some Python/system/program files, which could cause trouble later.

Comment: @Eric Duminil Ah, `range_iterator` indeed has that optimization, but it's too late! The `range` object uses the Python `1` as `step`, and then the iterator reads it's value 2. And here I was, thinking lack of that optimization might be another reason why [`range` is so slow](https://tio.run/##RY5LDoMwDET3OYWXAbEAsUFIXKFXqPiYNlJip66R6OlTKLTdeeaNRxNfemeqmygpzcIB1AV0Ci5EFj2V@RCnKMrsn18oGLE/4cje46iO6YcnfCxoDEEHVZnnjZlZ4AqOQHq6oa2z1sDurX@PsuKstRcmLID2EERxpPYYY30fhqlvj367FlBuT7SEAaWrtnPNUnoD).

Comment: @KellyBundy Thank you for finding small mistakes in my stackoverflow answers. [Here's a tribute](https://github.com/bharel/4to5).

Comment: @Bharel The `4 - 1` is rather hilarious :-)

Comment: @kelly `3+(1+1) < 3+1+1` is also intriguing

Answer (score 39):

In Python 2, there's a much simpler approach - `True` and `False` aren't protected, so you could assign things to them.

```
>>> True = False
>>> (1 == 2) is True
True
```

Comment: Doesn't do it the asked-about way, though. Maybe I should've kept how I phrased it in the title. Although then according to [Python 2's definition of true/false](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), I think you could *switch* the values of `True` and `False` and still argue to have achieved the desired result (although still not in the requested way). Anyway, +1 from me because it at least does achieve the `(1 == 2) is True` and is interesting as well.

Comment: If `True = False` then shouldn't `False is True` be `False` (since it's `True`)?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft no, this value is distinct (resides in a different address of RAM). It's equal to the original value of `True` and compares negatively to both `True` and `False` after the reassignment.

Comment: Just some meta-thoughts: The origin of my question is that someone proposed a solution to another task where they intended to use O(1) extra memory by "marking" input numbers by negating them. I then pointed out that in Python, the negated numbers are new objects, so they took O(n) extra memory. That made me wonder whether we can *modify* the given int objects instead to actually achieve O(1). So what I meant was "make 1 == 2" as in "*make 1* equal 2" as in "modify 1 so it equals 2". But now I'm glad I didn't express that well, as I and many others appreciate your answer to what I did express.

Answer (score 12):

If you'd prefer not to mess with the actual contents of cached `int` or `bool` objects, you can fake making `1 == 2` like so:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> import sys
>>>
>>> def displayhook(value):
...     if value is False:
...         value = True
...     elif value is 1:
...         value = 2
...     text = repr(value)
...     sys.stdout.write(text)
...     sys.stdout.write('\n')
...     builtins._ = value
...
<stdin>:4: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
>>> sys.displayhook = displayhook
>>> 1
2
>>> 1 == 2
True
```

Comment: `'Good' if 1 == 2 else 'Bad'` will still result in `Bad` though.

Comment: For people like me, that don't know python too well, it is could be useful to know that this is an interactive interpreter session, thus [`sys.displayhook()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook) can be used to modify the output: "this function prints repr(value) to sys.stdout".
Another thing I didn't know: `_` refers to the result of the last executed statement in interactive sessions.